# Confusion between Microcanonical and Canonical ensemble distributions

Tags: statistical-mechanics, gravity

This question is motivated by [this paper](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2020ApJ...905...11G/abstract).

The authors use statistical mechanics, but they don't specify which ensemble they use. They assume the Boltzmann distribution for the equilibrium state (equation 3).

Ignoring angular momentum for now, the Boltzmann distribution can be derived from the statistical definition for entropy,

$$S = -\sum_i p_i \ln p_i, $$

where $i$ marks different possible states within the system, and we have constant $N$ and $U$ constraints,

$$ N = \sum_i p_i,  \qquad \qquad U = \sum_i u_i p_i,$$

we can use Lagrange multipliers to find the max $S$ subject to the above constraints. Our Lagrange function is,

$$\mathcal{L}(p_i;\alpha,\beta) = -\sum_i p_i \ln p_i - \alpha\left(N - \sum_i p_i\right) - \beta\left(U - \sum_i p_i u_i \right),  $$

which can be used to find,

$$ p_i = \frac{N}{Z} e^{-\beta u_i}, $$

where,

$$ Z = \sum_i e^{-\beta u_i}. $$

Now, this looks like the canonical ensemble, but it was derived with microcanonical constraints (constant $N$ and $U$). **Which ensemble is this exactly?** I have an inkling it has something to do with the levels $i$.

Related questions were asked in [Definition of entropy for canonical vs. microcanonical ensembles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/469792/definition-of-entropy-for-canonical-vs-microcanonical-ensembles) and [Microcanonical ensemble confusion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/327971/microcanonical-ensemble-confusion), but those answers don't really answer my question.

I partially ask this question because [this paper](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2017ApJ...842...90R/abstract) mentions that the canonical and microcanonical ensembles may yield different answers in gravitational systems (see Section 2.3). Thus, it seems like it's quite important to specify which ensemble is assumed in gravitational statistical mechanics.

Comment: $\sum_i p_i u_i$ is the *average* energy, so it's indeed a canonical constraint. The constraint $\sum_i p_i = 1$ is just a normalization (making the $p_i$ a probability distribution). In the microcanonical ensemble, you only consider microstates with a *fixed* value of the energy.

Comment: Forgive me, but $\sum_i p_i u_i$ reads as total energy to me. Thus this looks like "maximize $S$ subject to the constraint that the total $U$ is fixed" which would mean microcanonical. However, I do see that $N^{-1} \sum_i p_i u_i$ would be average energy per $i$. Perhaps it would be helpful to see what a proper fixed value of energy constraint would look like.

Comment: Is exactly as @YvanVelenik said. These notes might be of help: https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~mevans/sp/sp2.pdf.

Comment: Those notes did help. I realized my problem was not properly understanding the Gibbs entropy equation. I was thinking of the $p_i$ as occupation numbers (e.g. level $i$ has energy $u_i$ and is occupied by $p_i$ particles). In fact, $p_i$ is the probability that the system is in microstate $i$ with energy $U_i$.

Comment: OK, so I'm still not understanding something. @YvanVelenik the $p_i$ above are occupation numbers for different energy levels in a single state, not probabilities for different microstates with different energies. In this case $\sum_i p_i u_i$ is the total energy of a single state. Note that the other paper (Roupas et al. 2017) I linked in my comment uses the same Boltzmann distribution seemingly for both the microcanonical and canonical ensemble (derived in equations 18-27 used in equations 42, 44-45 and mentioned in the paragraph between equations 49 and 50).

Comment: @Alex, you'll get proper probabilities from the $p_i's$ dividing them by $N$. Entropy is a property of probability distributions.

Comment: @Javi, my problem is not with probability vs. occupation number. The problem is single state vs. different states. The problem is that $\sum_i p_i u_i$ is the total energy of a state with $u_i$ energy levels. Sure, $N^{-1} \sum_i p_i u_i$ is the average energy per level in that state. Are we considering each energy level in the system to be a subsystem (separate microstate) in thermal contact with the other levels? This might explain why the Roupas et al. 2017 paper uses the Boltzmann distribution for the microcanonical and canonical case.

Comment: @Alex, Are you sure that the $p_i's$ represent a particular realization of the system? It could be that they are the average occupation number, in that case, you'd remove the state-dependence that concerns you. Otherwise, yes, I would say that a single particle might be the microstate.